# Unable to change city using proxy settings in ChromeDriver with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I am trying to change cities by setting the proxy using Selenium in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

proxy = '198.49.68.80:80'

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.iplocation.net/")
```

However, the webpage is still displaying my home town. I have taken proxies from this [free proxy list](https://free-proxy-list.net/).

I have tried adding this before `driver.get()`:

```
driver.delete_all_cookies()
```

And also adding the following options:

```
options.add_argument('–ignore-ssl-errors=yes')
options.add_argument('–ignore-certificate-errors')
```

Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Once you add the argument:

```
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)
```

You need to pass the *`options`* object as an argument while initiating the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) / [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) combo as follows:

- Using [selenium3](/questions/tagged/selenium3):

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
  ```
- Using [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4):

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)
  s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
  driver.get('https://www.iplocation.net/')
  ```
- Observation: Using a free *Proxy* from the [**Free Proxy List**](https://free-proxy-list.net/) being located in APAC region I was identified at *New Mexico*

[image: Mexico]

Comment: Thank you for your thourough answer. Unfortunately I realised that when making my minimal example, I missed out the `options=options` argument. I have been using Docker where this shows the same problem despite including the `options=options`. I will post another question after some more research.