# How to use a proxy with Selenium Python and ChromeDriver Chrome

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to find a solution in this site but all the sripts don't work. I use the proxies of https://hidemy.name/en/proxy-list/ . I ask help to do this script.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
import time

proxy_ip_port = '172.67.179.58:80'
proxy = Proxy()
proxy.proxy_type = ProxyType.MANUAL
proxy.http_proxy = proxy_ip_port
proxy.ssl_proxy = proxy_ip_port

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
proxy.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/tmp/chromedriver', desired_capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get('https://www.mio-ip.it/')
time.sleep(8)
driver.quit()
```

I tried this script but don't work

Answer (score 0):

Using [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) you can set the [proxy](/questions/tagged/proxy) using the [`--proxy-server`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75544071/7429447) argument as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

proxy_ip_port = '172.67.179.58:80'
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy_ip_port)
s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get('https://www.iplocation.net/')
```

Comment: Thanks to the reply! So, i have to change only this: 172.67.179.58:80      right?